# Kerio group calendaring private/public functionality

Tags: exchange, calendar, kerio

We are considering a change of email servers and Kerio Connect is attractive.  However, I am concerned about calendaring functionality.  I found an [old forum post](http://forums.kerio.com/index.php?t=msg&th=12162&start=0/) that states the question well:

> "We want to create a single public calendar that everyone can see - using
>   Windows XP/Outlook 2003/KOC 6.4.1. We
>   want a way for people to put an entry
>   in their own personal calendar and
>   some how mark it so the entry auto
>   add's or syncs with the public one. If
>   an entry is private it wouldn't sync
>   to the shared public calendar...
>
> Has anyone ever heard of a way to do
>   this - in any way with any software?"

This is a high priority feature, so if Kerio cannot do this, we may consider Exchange.  Does Exchange provide functionality like that described?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any product that provides such a specific feature, and I've used Kerio in the past.  I've not used Exchange, but there are some security questions that the proposal raises in my mind, so I'm suspicious that you would find someone that supports that.

If you are sufficiently interested, you may consider finding a tool that is sufficiently open, and essentially writing a tool to do this.  The functionality sounds simple enough.

To summarize, you could create a calendar for everyone called PublicSync (or whatever, just make it consistent for coding simplicity) and regularly update the public calendar with the combination of all of the PublicSync calendars.

Alternatively, users could all share their PublicSync calendars with everyone, and Outlook can effectively combine them (I think it has a UI to show a bunch of calendars effectively merged; I could be wrong).  You could do that with Kerio OR Exchange OR any Outlook integrating calendar product.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I've never used a group calendaring system, so it's helpful for me to find out that this kind of functionality is perhaps not the best way to go as far as security/privacy.